# Method invocation with timer in windows forms

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have created a datatable with ten columns and I get row values from my parallel port.

What I want to do is, when I invoke `gettable()` method, create a row with new array of data and insert this row after my previous row.

I tried with the code below, but all rows with same value. How can I achieve my desired behaviour?

```
 public DataTable GetTable(int rownumber)
 {
     DataTable table = new DataTable();

     try
     {
         listBox1.Items.Add("Row Count......" + rownumber);

         //
         // Here we create a DataTable with four columns.
         //

         table.Columns.Add("Channel1", typeof(double));
         table.Columns.Add("Channel2", typeof(double));
         table.Columns.Add("Channel3", typeof(double));
         table.Columns.Add("Channel4", typeof(double));
         table.Columns.Add("Channel5", typeof(double));
         table.Columns.Add("Channel6", typeof(double));
         table.Columns.Add("Channel7", typeof(double));
         table.Columns.Add("Channel8", typeof(double));
         table.Columns.Add("Channel9", typeof(double));
         table.Columns.Add("Channel10", typeof(double));
         table.Columns.Add("Channel11", typeof(double));

         //
         // Here we add DataRows.
         //
         DataTable row;

         for(int i = 0; i <= rownumber; i++)
         {
             row = table.newRow();
             row["Channel1"] = value1;
             row["Channel2"] = value2;
             table.Rows.Add(row);
         }
```

Comment: Where are value1 and value2 coming from? As shown, the loop is using the same values each time round.

Comment: Values are coming from External device which is connected through parallel port

Comment: If the values being added to the table are always the same, the problem may lie with the way they are being read from the device. The above code doesn't show any of that so it's going to be hard for anyone to help unless they've had the same problem.

Comment: they are double type values,but every time new values.I just wanted to write new row with new values.

Comment: Every row you insert into this table has the same values for the value1 and value2 variables. It sounds like you need to insert the values read from your parallel port.

Answer (score 0):

Every row you insert into this table has the same values for the value1 and value2 variables.  It sounds like you need to insert the values read from your parallel port.